# Python: *args behaviour in class methods

Tags: python

I am trying to write a wrapper Python function that takes in a variable number of positional arguments, which are then processed and fed into a main function from a library. I've created a minimal example here that shows the issue I'm currently facing:

```
class bar :
    def __init__(self, *args) :
        print(args)
    def foo(self,*args) :
        print(args)

a = bar('name',123,'def')
bar.foo('name',123,'def')
```

The output is :

> ('name', 123, 'def')
>
> (123, 'def')

It looks like 'name' is being assigned to `self` in `foo()`, but not in `__init__()`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why are you calling the method off of the class `bar`? If you do that, then it is *simply the function you have defined*, **not a method** because it hasn't had the instance bound, `self` is **just the first argument to a function**. Nothing special. This is *what you should expect*

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in drawing up this example, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method on the class `bar.foo` when you should be calling the method on the instance `a.foo`.

```
a.foo('name',123,'def')
```

Comment: Ah yes, indeed, what a stupid mistake. Thanks. I'll accept this as the answer when stackoverflow allows me to in a few minutes.